# Ipad Safari form inside iframe inside modal cursor jump

Tags: javascript, ios, ipad, iframe, safari

I have a problem with Safari on Iphone/Ipad with some modal windows.

On this page https://www.oneinterpreting.com/testpage.html, by pressing on submit request button, a modal window show up and inside it, I have an iframe with a form. The problem is that this form is jumping all around like in this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xVAGoaqowDM, and this is only with Safari on Iphone/Ipad.

I found this answer :
[iframe form inside bootstrap modal jump on keypress on iPhone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42151168/iframe-form-inside-bootstrap-modal-jump-on-keypress-on-iphone)

and this bug reported on: https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=158276

and they say that the bug was fixed in IOS 10.3 and later,

but we test with IOS 11.1 and browser: AppleWebKit/604.3.5 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/11.0 Mobile/15B93 Safari/604.1

and the problem still persists like in video above.

Please help.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Maybe this can help: [iOS 11 Safari bootstrap modal text area outside of cursor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46339063/ios-11-safari-bootstrap-modal-text-area-outside-of-cursor)